# Change subnet with bash script

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I'm looking to change every instance of 192.168.XXX in a file to 192.168.yyy. in a network config file using a bash script. The thing hanging me up is that I don't know for sure what xxx is going to be. For example it could be 192.168.122.1 or 192.168.123.1.  Also it could be 192.168.122.2 or 192.168.122, etc. I think this can be done with one command.

Here is the default network file:

```
    <network>
      <name>default</name>
      <bridge name="virbr0" />
      <forward/>
      <ip address="192.168.122.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
        <dhcp>
          <range start="192.168.122.2" end="192.168.122.254" />
        </dhcp>
      </ip>
    </network>
```

Comment: The accepted answer (from sudo_o) doesn't quite work.  For example, with `fip 192.168.247 192.168.73.1 192.168.188.13 192.168.123` in file t1, command `sed 's/192.168.[0-9]*\.\([0-9]*\)/192.168.15.\1/' t1` produces `fip 192.168.247 192.168.15.1 192.168.188.13 192.168.123` while my answer produces `fip 192.168.15 192.168.15.1 192.168.15.13 192.168.15`

Comment: @jwpat7 you are mistaken. The op asks to change only the 3 portion of IP address and provides an example of the files he needs to change. You have misunderstood, you can't have an IP address in format aaa.bbb.ccc so your point is moot.

Comment: @sudo_o, question says: “Also it could be 192.168.122.2 or 192.168.122”.  Re 3-group form see link at end of my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sed command

```
NEWIP=YYY
sed "s/192\.168\.[0-9]*/192.168.$NEWIP/g" filename
```

(with some number in place of YYY) will change 192.168.XXX to 192.168.YYY, and by doing that will change forms 192.168.XXX.ZZZ to 192.168.YYY.ZZZ as well.  The `g` in `s/.../.../g` says to change all of the matches on a line, instead of just the first.   As shown, it will output the result on stdout.  If you want to edit a file in place, use the -i switch:

```
sed -i "s/192\.168\.[0-9]*/192.168.$NEWIP/g" filename
```

If you want to edit a file in place after making a backup of the original with extension ~, you can say:

```
sed -i~ "s/192\.168\.[0-9]*/192.168.$NEWIP/g" filename
```

Note, changing entries of form 192.168.122 (ie entries which have three parts instead of four) was done as requested in question; however, a change like that does not necessarily make sense.  As noted in [LarsH's answer](https://superuser.com/a/486904) to  [Why does pinging 192.168.072 (only 2 dots) return a response from 192.168.0.58?](https://superuser.com/questions/486788) the IP dotted form `A.B.C` is equivalent to `A.B.0.C`, and if that convention is followed it does not make sense to change 192.168.122 (with value 192.168.0.122) to say 192.168.15 (with value 192.168.0.15).

Comment: The use of the `NEWIP` variable is very clunky, plus the OP asked for a one liner which this is not. You should learn about using capture groups `s/\(^capture this line.$\)/\1/` where `\1` referred to the matched line starting with `capture this line`. I did forget the `/g` for global matching however, thanks.

Comment: who do I award, technically the previous one was correct but yours is correcter ..lol

Comment: Both can be consider *equally correct* but you should accept the first correct answer.. mine :)

Comment: @MikeQ, *upvote* any answer that you find useful.  *Select* whichever answer helps you more or has the clearer explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The following `sed` one liner will change the 3rd portion of an IP *(to 15 in this example)* and leave the other 2 or 3 portions unchanged.

`sed -r 's/192\.168(\.??[0-9]*){2}/192.168.15\1/g'`

Output:

```
192.168.0.12
192.168.15.12

192.168.25.34
192.168.15.34

192.168.0
192.168.15
```

So to change all the IP's from `192.168.XXX.YYY` to `192.168.15.YYY` or `192.168.XXX` to `192.168.YYY`  in `network.conf` run

`sed -r 's/192\.168(\.??[0-9]*){2}/192.168.15\1/g' network.conf`

This will display the file to `stdout` with the changes, if you are happy with the changes use the `-i` option to save the changes to the file.

`sed -r -i 's/192\.168(\.??[0-9]*){2}/192.168.15\1/g' network.conf`

Just remember to change `192.168.15.\1` to `192.168.XXX.\1` where `XXX` is the actual number you need *(not 15)* and change the filename also *(from network.conf).*

Comment: FYI double quotes:     sed -e "s/192.168.[0-9]*\.\([0-9]*\)/192.168.${NEW_RAND_SUBNET}.\1/" ${FIREWRULE}
  cat ${FIREWRULE} | sed -e "s/192.168.[0-9]*\.\([0-9]*\)/192.168.${NEW_RAND_SUBNET}.\1/"

Comment: Just realized it's not changing the second one "192.168.122.254"... Any ideas?

Comment: Yes sed only replaces the first match on each line, to replace all matches on a line we need to use `/g`. This is how you need your command `sed -e "s/192.168.[0-9]*\.([0-9]*)/192.168.${NEW_RAND_SUBNET}.\1/g" ${FIREWRULE} cat ${FIREWRULE} | sed -e "s/192.168.[0-9]*\.([0-9]*)/192.168.${NEW_RAND_SUBNET}.\1/g"`

Comment: Made match lazy to fit both 3 portion and 4 portions IP, still a one liner and doesn't replace `192.168.0junk` with `192.168.15junk` like jwpat7 answer does.